# Windows explorer activity watch

Tags: windows, api

I wanna write a program which records all the folders and files a User browse using Windows Explorer.

I already have a soluton of using *GetForegroundWindow*, *GetWindowText* and *FindWindow* APIs every few milliseconds (a timer) in order to keep this record. But there might be a better solution out there.

any idea?

Comment: Why restrict your attentions to Explorer? There are soooo many more ways to browse the file system.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. any solution for general browsing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mini-filter to monitor all I/O actions. ;-)

Comment: bah be shooma! :D  
example please?

Comment: bah be khodetoon... For example we have done Negahban Project in APA.... Perhaps I can send you the drivers :D

Comment: daste shuma dard nakone, ... but to be honest, I really can't remember why I asked this Q anymore! :D